# Need help to understand LPeg and PEGs

Tags: lua, peg, lpeg

The following pattern (from [this page](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/lpeg/)) matches only strings with balanced parentheses:

```
b = lpeg.P{ "(" * ((1 - lpeg.S"()") + lpeg.V(1))^0 * ")" }
```

What does `1-` in `1 - lpeg.S"()"` mean?

```
function gsub (s, patt, repl)
  patt = lpeg.P(patt)
  patt = lpeg.Cs((patt / repl + 1)^0)
  return lpeg.match(patt, s)
end
```

What does the `+1` in `patt / repl + 1` mean?

And I still not quite get the function of prioritized choice operator `/` very well from this [paper](http://bford.info/pub/lang/peg.pdf)

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `1` in `1 - lpeg.S"()"` means any character. The whole statement can be read as, match any character while not matching a character in the set `"()"`.

The `+1` is the same idea, if `repl` is a string then `patt / repl + 1` matches pattern `patt` and then replaces it's capture with the string `repl` or skips a character.

Comment: Generally, whenever LPEG may accept a pattern as an argument, it may also accept a plain number(or string, or boolean, etc.) and will implicitly convert it to a pattern using lpeg.P(). And lpeg.P(1) means "any character".